# Combo: Unambiguous expression - String

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am stuck on finding an unambiguous express so that it can produce all the strings in the given set, for the set of binary strings where for each block of zero's which are of length minimum 3 must be followed by a block of ones of even length.

Comment: Do you mean that each block of zeroes must be of length at least $3$, or do you mean that shorter blocks of $0$s are allowed, but if a block of $0$s does have length at least $3$, then it must be followed by a block of an even number of $1$s?

Comment: "Express(ion)"? Do you have some particular programming language in mind or what? Or a _regular expression_? Or instead of "producing" the strings, are you looking merely to _count_ them?

Comment: @Henning: Probably regular expression.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, that just struck me too. In that case "combinatorics" is not really the right tag, it shoudl be "formal-languages".

Answer (score 0):

```
1*(01(1*)+001(1*)+000(0*)11((11)*))*
```

I don't know if there's a better one.. Probably it does..